# Change color to a shape added as subview

Tags: ios, swift

I created a `UIView`, called CircleView, that draws a circle. This was added with a click of a button and located with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in another view, canvasView, as a subview.
This is the code for circle and it works:

```
@IBAction func tapCircle(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint2 = sender.location(in: canvasView)
        let shapeCircle = CircleView(origin: tapPoint2)
        canvasView.addSubview(shapeCircle)
        shapeCircle.tag = 300        
}

@IBAction func circleDraw(_ sender: UIButton) {
        canvasView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tapCircle.isEnabled = true
        tapRect.isEnabled = false
        tapGRQ.isEnabled = false

        canvasView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

It's all okay but i'm wondering if it is possible to change the color of this shape with a click of a button. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to identify the shape by giving a tag for every shape and then you can change the color.

Comment: @guru Identification of views using tags is not exactly the best solution. Use an instance variable instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create global variables for arrays of shapes

```
var circleShapes = [UIView]()
var squareShapes = [UIView]()
...
```

then append new `UIView` to certain array after you create it

```
let shapeCircle = CircleView(origin: tapPoint2)
canvasView.addSubview(shapeCircle)
circleShapes.append(shapeCircle)
...
```

now just change `backgroundColor` for each view inside certain array

```
circleShapes.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = /* UIColor */ }
...
```

---

Or if your `canvasView` contains just *shapes* subviews, every *shape* has its own `UIView` subclass and you want to change colors in the same time, you can change `backgroundColor` depending on type of *shape*

```
canvasView.subviews.forEach {
    switch $0 {
    case is CircleView:
        $0.backgroundColor = /* UIColor */
    case is SquareView:
        $0.backgroundColor = /* UIColor */
    ...
    default:
        continue
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 type of shapes added as subview and i can added as many i want. Can i use the code above?

Comment: @SashaDavies if you need for all shapes the same color

Comment: i'm sorry for the question, if i'd like to set different color for each shape how can i do? thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the help but it set all the view color, now i see a white circle inside a red square. my question is if i could color only the circle inside the view. I'm sorry for the question again

Comment: @SashaDavies you have `canvasView` and inside this view is circles and squares, right? You need to just color circles? Then just change color for each view inside `circleShapes`

Comment: It works for rect shape and square shape, only the circle has problems because it's inside a rect frame: init (origin: CGPoint){
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size, height: size))
        self.center = origin}

Comment: @SashaDavies what? How is this related with frame? You're just changing `backgroundColor` of `UIView`, don't you?

Comment: I resolve the problem, thank you so much Robert for your help!!

Comment: it missed self.clipsToBounds = true in the View where i created the circle